# Access to YouTube Live API

Tags: youtube-api

I am a developer working on an open-source project called Freeseer (http://freeseer.github.io/) it is used for recording conferences and talks. I would like to bring live streaming to Freeseer, however in order to develop and test live streaming I need a Google account with 100 subscribers (as listed here http://www.youtube.com/yt/creators/creator-benefits.html).

I am not asking for subscribers, nor am I interested in monetization of the account. I simply want to know if Google provides developer accounts, or can grant development privileges.

(I am well aware this is not a technical question, it is much more suited for a Google group or developer forum, unfortunately the existing one has been closed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 100 subscriber restriction was removed last month.

http://apiblog.youtube.com/2013/12/3-2-1-and-you-are-live.html

Comment: Thank you, guess I just have to wait it out for a bit.

Comment: UPDATE: I have livestream access, I would upvote if I had the rep.